# How do I add 3 dot overflow menu on custom action bar for Oreo?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-menu, overflow-menu

I want to add **overflow menu** on my custom action bar. I know, I can add new settings activity but that's too confusing, and I wanted to know the exact code to add those.

I have seen few posts, but it was limited to older SDKs. As I am using custom layout for my action bar. Please help me so that code could work for Android 8.0 and for sdk's lower than that.

My code is as follows:

**HomescreenActivity.java** :-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);

   }
```

**activity_homescreen.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/paper_planes_color_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomescreenActivity">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
       android:id="@+id/recy_category"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**abs_layout.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you use custom actionbar then you can use imageview for those 3 dots. if u agree i will post you answer how to use it

Comment: Post it please, I am new to android....

Comment: check my post, it helps you

Comment: @earthw0rmjim By using your mention post, I got the solution for my problem which i have added here, thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override "**onCreateOptionsMenu()**" method, and mention your menu through "***menu/your_menu_file.xml*** ", and to handle menu click listener override "**onOptionsItemSelected**" method

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> **custom_toolbar_layout :**

include this layout in your activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_back_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> **ic_more_vert_black_24dp :**

You can get 3 dots icon from android default **vector or images assets**. For this, Right Click on **res** **>** **New** **>** **Vector Asset**, then from **Clipart** you can get this icon as :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,10c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2s0.9,2 2,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,16c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2s0.9,2 2,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z"/>
```

Comment: I am working on it, but it requires work around, there must be a direct method for that...

Comment: @prasad_21 you can achieve these in other way also, but i show you how to add custom 3 3dots in custom toolbar, if it helps you please upvote it. Thanks!